If $eR \cap fR = 0$, Is it true that $R=(1-e)R + (1-f)R$?
Let $R$ be a ring with unity, and let $e,f\in R$ be two idempotents such that $eR \cap fR=0$. Is it ture that $R=(1-e)R + (1-f)R$?
Attempt: If $x\in R$, then $x=ex+(1-e)x$. As $e=fe+(1-f)e$, then $ex=fex+(1-f)ex$. So, $x=fex+(1-f)ex+(1-e)x$.
Unfortunately, I don't know how to complete the proof. Any help? Any counter-example?

Excuse me. How did you get $f=(1-e)s$ for some $s\in R$? @Amateur_Algebraist

Well if $R$ was commutative (or just $ef=fe$) we have $ef=0$ since it lies in the intersection, hence $f=(1-e)f$. But not sure what to do in general. Are you sure your ring is not commutative?

Yes. $R$ is not necessarily commutative.

Then I suggest that you try to look for counterexamples (and you can add your ideas to the post). In fact there is a universal one.

I think your statement is true for semisimple rings, but not sure about the general case.

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[e,f]/\langle e^2-e,f^2-f\rangle$, where $e,f$ are non-commuting indeterminates. Then $R$ has basis over $\mathbb{Z}$ consisting of all finite alternating sequences of $e,f$.  Then $eR$ has $\mathbb{Z}$ basis consisting of alternating sequences beginning with $e$.  Similarly, $fR$ has $\mathbb{Z}$ basis consisting of alternating sequences beginning with $f$.
Clearly then $eR\cap fR=0$ as their $\mathbb{Z}$ basis' are disjoint subsets of a $\mathbb{Z}$ basis for $R$.
Further we have a ring homomorphism $\epsilon \colon R \to \mathbb{Z}$, sending $e,f\mapsto 1$.
Then $(1-e)R+(1-f)R$ lies in the kernel of $\epsilon$, and is therefore not all of $R$.

+1. This is what I meant with the "universal example" in my comment above.

@MartinBrandenburg Yes, just forcing the minimum number of things to hold that are required is often the way to go with these things.  My first thought was to look at matrices with $0$'s and $1$'s along the diagonals, but that does not work here.
